# EF Core is lazy loading when I try to eager load with .Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2.6 (database first) and it seems like just having lazy loading enabled keeps me from being able to eager load. Does enabling lazy loading preclude using eager loading in any capacity?

```cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class Lead
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public LeadOrganization LeadOrganization { get; set; }

        public Lead(ExampleContext.Data.Lead dbLead)
        {
            Id = dbLead.Id;
            LeadOrganization = new LeadOrganization(dbLead.LeadOrganization);
        }

        public static Lead GetLead(int id)
        {
            using (var db = new ExampleContext())
            {
                var dbLead = db.Leads
                    .Include(l => l.LeadOrganization)
                        .ThenInclude(lo => lo.LeadOrganizationAddresses)
                            .ThenInclude(loa => loa.AddressType)
                    .FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id== id);

                return new Lead(dbLead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class LeadOrganization
    {
        public IEnumerable<LeadOrganizationAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

        public LeadOrganization(ExampleContext.Data.LeadOrganization dbLeadOrganization)
        {
            Addresses = dbLeadOrganization.LeadOrganizationAddresses.Select(loa => new LeadOrganizationAddress(loa));
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class LeadOrganizationAddress
    {
        public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }

        public LeadOrganizationAddress(ExampleContext.Data.LeadOrganizationAddress dbLeadOrganizationAddress)
        {
            AddressType = new AddressType(dbLeadOrganizationAddress.AddressType);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace Example.Models
{
    public class AddressType
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }

        public AddressType(ExampleContext.Data.AddressType dbAddressType)
        {
            Id = dbAddressType.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

The `ExampleContext.Data` namespace contains the EF-generated partial classes from the database. `Lead`, `LeadOrganization`, `LeadOrganizationAddress`, and `AddressType` are classes that are basically 1:1 with the partials in terms of properties, but with static methods added (yes it's weird, but it's what I have to work with).

A Lead has a LeadOrganization, which in turn has at least one LeadOrganizationAddress, which in turn has an AddressType.

When `GetLead` calls the `Lead` constructor, the data from the query has not loaded, even though it should be eager loaded. This leads to problems down the line of nested objects. When it eventually gets to the `LeadOrganizationAddress` constructor, the DbContext has been disposed, and thus can't lazy load the associated `AddressType`.

Am I misunderstanding the whole point of eager loading? I thought it would retrieve all the data upon the initial query, letting me then pass that to the constructor without issue. I shouldn't need to keep going back to the database and lazy load anything.

Can you simply not eager load if you have lazy loading enabled? Is there some other workaround like forcing it to load any proxied entities?

Comment: "*lead.LeadOrganization is a proxy as it hasn't actually retrieved the data yet*" I don't think such state exists. The property is either `null` (not loaded) or instance (proxy or not doesn't matter) which is loaded. EF Core does not create fake instances, and the proxy class probably is for lazy loading related data to `LeadOrganization` entity not shown in your example. Also it's unclear what do you mean by "as expected" and what problems with constructors of the nested entities are you talking about. I think it's better to provide [mcve].

Comment: I've updated my post to be a bit more clear as to what I'm trying to do and what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after investigating the issue, there is a problem with EF Core 2.x lazy loading via proxies implementation. The related tracked issues are

- [#15170: Eager loading include with using UseLazyLoadingProxies](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15170)
- [#12780: Store IsLoaded flags in proxy for better lazy-loading experience](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12780)

The problem is that the navigation properties *are* eager loaded, but `LazyLoader` does not know that when disposed - can't safely access context change tracker and simply is throwing exception. The relevant code can be seen [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/v2.2.6/src/EFCore/Internal/LazyLoader.cs#L86), in the very first line:

```
if (_disposed)
{
    Logger.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning(Context, entity, navigationName);
}
```

As I read it, it's supposed to be fixed in EF Core 3.0 when released with the following "breaking change" - [Lazy-loading proxies no longer assume navigation properties are fully loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#lazy-loading-proxies-no-longer-assume-navigation-properties-are-fully-loaded). It also partially explains the current problem:

> **Old behavior**
>
> Before EF Core 3.0, once a `DbContext` was disposed there was no way of knowing if a given navigation property on an entity obtained from that context was fully loaded or not.

Unfortunately this doesn't help you with the current problem. The options I see are:

1. Wait for EF Core 3.0 release
2. Don't use lazy loading via proxies
3. Turn off the lazy loading on disposed context warning - by default it is `Throw`, change it to `Log` or `Ignore`, for instance:

   ```
   optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings
       .Log(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning)
   );
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` but want to disable the lazy loading for specific Includes in your queries. This is not implemented yet:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10787

The only thing what you can do right now:

1.) Disable the lazy-loading proxy ("default lazy loading for all properties")

2.) Then use (manual implemented) lazy-loading for specific properties, for example in one of your cases:

```
public class LeadOrganization
{
    private ILazyLoader _lazyLoader { get; set; }

    private IEnumerable<LeadOrganizationAddress> _addresses;

    public LeadOrganization(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        _lazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    public IEnumerable<LeadOrganizationAddress> Addresses
    {
        get => _addresses;
        set => _addresses = value;
    }

    public IEnumerable<LeadOrganizationAddress> AddressesLazy
    {
        get
        {
            _lazyLoader?.Load(this, ref _addresses);
        }
        set => this._addresses = value;
    }
}
```

So for eager-loading use `.Include(lo=>lo.Addresses)`, for lazy-loading use `.Include(lo=>lo.AddressesLazy)`

---

**Edit 1**

IMO lazy loading shouldn't be enabled per default for all properties - this could impact the performance of your whole implementation. So the solution above is one alternative in cases where lazy loading brings you advantages. I also would like to have this option in every include, something like `.Include(o=>o.Addresses, LoadingBehaviour.Eager)` - maybe this will exist in the future.

Comment: The above code should obviously beeing used within your entity classes (after reading your comment)

Comment: I agree with not having lazy loading on by default, I enabled it as a catch-all for existing code when we moved a project from EF to EF Core, since if you don't eager load a property and try to use it it's simply null.

So EF Core will try to use lazy loading (if enabled for everything) even when you try to eager load?

Comment: Yes @Gabe - "right now" enabling the lazy-loading proxy on the db-context will enable it for all navigational properties...

Comment: Thanks for this temporal solution meanwhile there's no other option in EF core.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading isn't what's preventing the instantiation of your properties, lacking a proper constructor in them is.

EF Core aside, it's very strange that those types, e.g. `LeadOrganization` need to be passed in an instance of themselves in their constructor. It's kind of a chicken and egg problem – how do you create the first one?

```
public class LeadOrganization
{
    public IEnumerable<LeadOrganizationAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public LeadOrganization(ExampleContext.Data.LeadOrganization dbLeadOrganization)
    {
        Addresses = dbLeadOrganization.LeadOrganizationAddresses.Select(loa => new LeadOrganizationAddress(loa));
    }
}
```

In any case, [EF Core only supports simple constructors with parameters based on convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors) (basically a 1-1 mapping of parameters to properties), so it doesn't know how to instantiate and hydrate those nested classes, eager or lazy.

I suggest making those constructors parameterless, or if you want EF to hydrate the objects via properties, at least add a parameterless constructor to your classes.

Comment: Sorry, the example is a bit confusing. The classes I've shown are not the EF entity classes. They're 1:1 in terms of properties but have added methods, so the constructor takes in an entity class and translates it to the model we're using. I've updated the namespace to help clarify.

You'll see `AddressType` is in `Example.Models`, but the constructor takes in `ExampleContext.Data.AddressType` as a parameter.